# .htaccess RewriteRule 404 Not Found

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm having issues with .htaccess  RewriteRule. all I'm trying to do is 
rewrite this url -   www.example.com/public/?q=admin
to - www.example.com/public/admin

but now when I go to this url www.example.com/public/admin it says not found.

but this url is working ww.example.com/public/?q=admin

here is my .htaccess code

```
Options All -Indexes

<FilesMatch "(config|.+\.html)\.php">
    deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(bmp|cgi|css|flv|gif|ico|jpe?g|js|png|swf|xml)$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule (.*) ?q=$1&%1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Does anyone know to help?

UPDATE
This script installed inside a subdomain and a sub folder
like this 
http://subdomain.maindomain.com/comingsoon/
coming soon is the root  folder
http://subdomain.maindomain.com/comingsoon/public is another folder where placed .htaccess  file.

I'm using mini  php framwork called Swiftlet

https://github.com/AliasIO/Swiftlet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule in your .htaccess for your required url.

```
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ public?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**UPDATE 1:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.domain.com
RewriteRule ^public/(.*)$ http://subdomain.domain.com/comingsoon/public?q=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: No luck.. it says

The requested URL /comingsoon/public/admin was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: are you Codignitor? @MalithMcR

Comment: the script installed inside a subdomain and a sub folder
like this 
http://subdomain.maindomain.com/comingsoon/
coming soon is the root  folder
http://subdomain.maindomain.com/comingsoon/public is another folder where placed .htaccess  file.

I'm using mini  php framwork called Swiftlet

https://github.com/AliasIO/Swiftlet

Comment: unfortunately still not working.. is it possible something wrong with hosting ? because In my localhost It's working perfectly. but after I uploaded to server it's not working..

Comment: Yes may be.. it may be authentication issue allowes .htaccess rules.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99976/discussion-between-devpro-and-malith-mcr).

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
.... use this line on top of htacces for production @malith-mcr

Comment: Thanks @devpro I've tried this already but no luck. I've just opened ticket to hosting company. waiting for their update.

Comment: @malith-mcr after getting response must update here. Becuase we spend lot of time here n now want to knw anything will help for others. Tc

Comment: Thanks for helping. I know value of time. i got response from ticket 
___
We tracked down the error - it was caused by a missing "/" in your htaccess file. 
__
but it's not resolved anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after your update, try this :

```
RewriteBase /comingsoon/public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: No luck.. it says

The requested URL /comingsoon/public/admin was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: what is this "comingsoon" ?

Comment: the script installed inside a subdomain and a sub folder
like this 
http://subdomain.maindomain.com/comingsoon/
coming soon is the root  folder
http://subdomain.maindomain.com/comingsoon/public is another folder where placed .htaccess  file.

I'm using mini  php framwork called Swiftlet

https://github.com/AliasIO/Swiftlet

Comment: Ok, I edited my post. If the .htaccess is not in your root folder, you should indicate a RewriteBase.

Comment: unfortunately still not working.. is it possible something wrong with hosting ? because In my localhost It's working perfectly. but after I uploaded to server it's not working..